# Creating indexing for dot annotated dynamic path in firestore [Wildcard]?

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore, composite-index

I have my collection created as below:

```
-products
  -productID
    -category [object]
      catitem1 - boolean
      catitem2 - boolean
```

now I have written a query as below

```
this.afs.collection<Product>('products', ref =>
    ref
      .where(`category.${categoryName}`, '==', true)
      .limit(limit)
);
```

This query works fine but when I add orderBy to the above query, I am asked to create an `index` for the query.

```
this.afs.collection<Product>('products', ref =>
    ref
      .where(`category.${categoryName}`, '==', true)
      .orderBy('createdDate','desc')
      .limit(limit)
);
```

Since the `categoryName` can be created and can be changed at anytime, I am supposed to add indexing for each and every categoryName which would be in hundreds.

Is there any way where I can create a wildcard index for `category.categoryName`?

I tried using `category.*` but that's not acceptable. Hope to find some help here.

Comment: did you find solution to this? I'm currently in the same situation

Comment: @ahmedjaad nope I did not.. I had to change my functionality..

Comment: Thanks for the response, our case is a bit different from yours though, in our case the variable is the language we support in our app, and we only support a limited number of languages so i guess i will stick with creating index for each language, Hopefully will see such feature in the firestore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question was asked, Firestore has implemented various operators to help with [querying for array membership](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership). The available operators at time of writing are: `array-contains`, `array-contains-any`, `in`, and `not-in`.

Instead of storing `category` as an `object` with a `Boolean` property for each `categoryName`, you could have a `categories` array that *only* contains the `String` names (or, if you want to save space, `Int` ids) of categories that the product is a member of.

The query could then work like this, which would require only a single index:

```js
this.afs.collection<Product>('products', ref =>
    ref
      .where('categories', 'array-contains', categoryName)
      .orderBy('createdDate','desc')
      .limit(limit)
);
```